# Show $z$ can be expressed as a function of $x$ and $y$ in the equation $x+y+z=\sin(xyz)$ near $x=y=z=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Show $z$ can be expressed as a function of $x$ and $y$ in the equation $x+y+z=\sin(xyz)$ near $x=y=z=0$, and find the partial derivatives of the solution with respect to $x$ and to $y$.

What I tried:

Let $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$, $g(x,y,z)=\sin(xyz)$, $F(x,y,z)=(f, g)$, I think then I should use implicit function theorem here, but

(1) The determinant of matrix of partial derivative $[DF/x, DF/y]=0$

(2) Even the determinant of (1) isn't $0$, what I got from implicit function is that functions of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$, not $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You can cheat a little by using $\sin(xyz)\approx xyz$.

Comment: In physics, that’s definitely true for all $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $F$ is not the function you want to work with. Instead, define

$$F(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z) - g(x,y,z)$$

Note that $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} (0,0,0) \neq 0$ and so you can apply the implicit function theorem to conclude that there exists a function $h$ defined on a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $F(x,y, h(x,y)) =0$ and $0=h(0,0)$

Comment: Thanks! I'm just still a little confused about this question, define F as in your answer, then at (0, 0, 0), f(0)=g(0), i.e., the equation x+y+z=sin(xyz) holds at 0. Then after using implicit function theorem, assuming we got z=h(x, y), then how do we know x+y+h(x, y)=sin(xyh(x, y)) also hold near 0, since near 0, F(x, y, z) doesn't need to be equal to 0.

Comment: That's what the implicit function theorem says. It says that you can find a function $h$ near $(0,0)$ such for any $(x,y)$ close to $(0,0)$, $(x,y,h(x,y))$ satisfies the equation. i.e. For $(x,y)$ close enough to $(0,0)$, you can solve for $z$ in the equation $F(x,y,z).= 0$

Comment: $h$ is not a random function. The implicit function theorem tells you you can find an $h$ such that if $z=h(x,y)$, then $F(x,y,z) = 0$.